# How to get optional opts type signature to compile - TS2394

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have this method, with 2 possibilities:

```
  requestLockInfo(key: string, cb: EVCb<any>): void;
  requestLockInfo(key: string, opts: any, cb: EVCb<any>): void;
  requestLockInfo(key: string, opts: any, cb: EVCb<any>) {
      // implementation
  }
```

the problem is it won't compile, it says:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Does anyone know how to create an optional options object in the signature like this? I have this problem a lot, and making the last argument optional with `cb?` doesn't usually solve the root problem.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation signature needs to basically be the result of merging the two other signatures. In this case that means:

```js
requestLockInfo(key: string, cb: EVCb<any>): void;
requestLockInfo(key: string, opts: any, cb: EVCb<any>): void;
requestLockInfo(key: string, opts: any | EVCb<any>, cb?: EVCb<any>) {
    // implementation
}
```

The second argument `opts` can be either `any` (in case of the signature with 3 arguments) or `EVCb<any>` (in case of the signature with 2 arguments).

The third argument `cb` needs to be optional because in case of the signature with 2 arguments, it is not defined.